# I want to load in a new class but only if the current page is single-movies.php

Tags: php, functions

I am trying to add an extra class to my div but only if the current page is being served up by my single-movies.php page.

The below code is what I was hoping would work but it doesn't.

```
<div class="sponsors <?php if(is_page('single-movies.php') { echo " movies" } ?>">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have a look at [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) which actually can check whether a specific template is used.

So your code should be like:

```
<div class="sponsors <?php if( is_page_template('single-movies.php') ) { echo " movies"; } ?>">
```

Be aware, that `is_page_template()` does not work within The Loop, [as written in the Codex.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/#cannot-be-used-inside-the-loop) You may have a look at the alternative which is mentioned there.

Edit:
Added in a ; after " movies"

Comment: So the above code gave me the following error.

Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/scera/wp-content/themes/scera/footer.php on line 21

Comment: Absolutely! My mistake, forgot a closing bracket, fixed the code above, please try again.

Comment: Oh I should have caught that hahaha you also forgot a ; I submitted an edit request.

Comment: Meh... :-D Time to got to bed obviously.